# In SSL handshake, is data gets encrypted before exchange of client pre-master?

Tags: ssl, sslhandshakeexception

More specific is server public key exchange is encrypted? If yes how can client decrypt server's public key?

Answer (score 1):

You seem very confused.

- The premaster secret is not exchanged. It is sent by the client.
- The server public key is not exchanged. It is sent by the server, in the certificate contained in the `Certificate` message.
- Unless there has been a prior handshake, nothing is encrypted until the `ChangeCipherSpec` message has been issued.
- That message is issued several steps after the premaster secret is sent.
- The server public key is not a secret and does not need to be encrypted.
- Unless the cipher suite is a DSA one, the client doesn't need the server's public key at all.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.

Comment: 1,2 correct for plain-RSA, but DHE and ECDHE (aka PFS) are now at least as common; 4 client CCS is immediately after ClientKX unless client-auth which is rare and server CCS is first in its response unless ticket which is also rare; 6 I don't know what you mean but client needs at least one server publickey (often two) for anything but pure SRP, pure PSK, or Kerberos, all of which are rare.